# Understanding PHP short tags

Tags: php, zend-framework

I saw this in [this video](http://www.zendcasts.com/using-blueprint-css-with-zend-2/2009/01/comment-page-1/#comment-55472) but I don't understand how does `<?=` work.
Can someone help me?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

That's the short format of `<?php echo`. It's always enabled in PHP 5.4 and higher, but otherwise you'll need [the `short_open_tag` option](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) to be enabled in `php.ini`.

Answer (score 2):

Generally php tags are `<?php ?>` or `<? ?>`. This tag `<?= ?>` is a shorter version of `<?php echo [some_var]; ?>`